# using subsample with PhotoImage in Tkinter and PIL

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

i folks,
I'm trying to use the subsample method in the PhotoImage class to resize an image I have in a list that links to a Label widget in Tkinter but python says there is no such method. I know I could use Image.resize before calling Photoimage but since I'd like to resize the image at any time I don't know what to do once it's been converted to PhotoImage. Could someone please show me what I'm doing wrong? I'm relatively new to Tkinter and very new to PIL...Thanks...

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class imgList(object):
        def __init__(self,imgs):
            self.list=[]
            for i in imgs:
                image=Image.open(i)
                photo=ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
                self.list.append(photo)

        def resize(self,num,fact):
            self.list[num]=self.list[num].subsample(fact)
            #image=image.resize((50,100),Image.ANTIALIAS)
            #photo=ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
            #photo.subsample(2,2)
            #self.list[num]=photo


class Slot(object):

    def __init__(self,root,canvas,appimg,x,y):
        self.root=root
        self.canvas=canvas
        self.appimage=appimg
        self.l=Label(self.root,image=self.appimage)
        self.l.place(x=x,y=y)

class View(object):
    def __init__(self,canvas):
        self.canvas=canvas

class win1(View):
    def slotbind(self,event):
        print("heloo")
        self.imglist.resize(0,2)
    def draw(self,root,tv):
        self.canvas.delete(ALL)
        self.root=root
        #self.photolist=pl
        self.imglist=imgList(["pic1.bmp"])
        self.tv=tv
        self.s1=Slot(self.root,self.canvas,self.imglist.list[0],10,10)
        self.s1.l.bind("<1>",self.slotbind)
        self.qbtn=Button(self.root,text="quit",command=self.quit)
        self.qbtn.place(x=270,y=100)
        self.qbtn.lift()
    def quit(self):
        self.qbtn.destroy()
        self.s1.l.destroy()
        self.tv[1].draw(self.root,self.tv)

class win2(View):
    def draw(self,root,tv):
        self.canvas.delete(ALL)
        self.root=root
        self.tv=tv
        imglist=imgList(["pic3.bmp","pic4.bmp"])
        self.s1=Slot(self.root,self.canvas,imglist.list[1],270,10)
        self.qbtn=Button(self.root,text="quit2",command=self.quit)
        self.qbtn.place(x=500,y=100)
        self.qbtn.lift()
    def quit(self):
        self.qbtn.destroy()
        self.s1.l.destroy()
        self.tv[0].draw(self.root,self.tv)

class win3(View):
    def draw(self):
        pass

class App(object):
    def __init__(self, width=640, height=480):

        self.width = width
        self.height = height

        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title("tkinter_test01")
        self.root.geometry("%sx%s"%(self.width, self.height))

        self.canvas = Canvas(self.root, width=self.width, height=self.height)

        self.theviews=[win1(self.canvas),win2(self.canvas),win3(self.canvas)]
        self.theviews[0].draw(self.root,self.theviews)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.root.mainloop()

app=App()
```

Answer (score 3):

Bad news, `subsample` and `zoom` are not available in `ImageTk.PhotoImage`, and only in `Tkinter.PhotoImage`. The later only accepts PPM, PGM, GIF, and if you are using Python with Tk 8.6b2 or later (very unlikely at this time) then there is also support for PNG images.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code will solve the problem - I tried it succesfully:

```
# http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm
import Tkinter
# from PIL 
import Image, ImageTk
im = Image.open('z:/g1.jpg')
# imc=im.copy()
imc=im.transpose(Image.ROTATE_270)
(x0,y0,x1,y1)=imc.getbbox() # returns (0,0,w,h)
print 'x0=%d y0=%d x1=%d y1=%d\n' % (x0,y0,x1,y1)
tkroot=Tkinter.Tk()
# tki=ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
# tkl=Tkinter.Label(tkroot, image=tki)
# tkl.pack()
imc.thumbnail((1+x1/5,1+y1/5)) # changes image in place!
tkic=ImageTk.PhotoImage(imc)
tklc=Tkinter.Label(tkroot,image=tkic)
tklc.pack()
tkroot.mainloop() # Start the GUI
```